# Is there an API call in AWS Elastic Beanstalk to have a list of running hosts? (with IPs)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

The title really says it all. I need each instance running to be aware of what the other instances are, including their IP addresses. Is there an EB API call to do that? Or maybe a more generic way in AWS?

Answer (score 0):

The AWS Elastic Beanstalk SDK exposes methods that provide details about both the Environment and Applications. (Not clear what you mean by  ***I need each instance running to be aware of what the other instances are***)

Anyhow -- you can get a list of applications and get details about those EB apps. For example, you can get the status (an EB app that is running will have a status value **Ready**) and the app URL (**not the IP**). SO you can get at the details you are looking for with the SDK.

Running this code returns details that you see the AWS Management Console -- such as:

- The application name is VideoAnalyzer
- The Environment ARN is arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-1:xxxxxx047983:environment/VideoAnalyzer/Videoanalyzer-env
- The Endpoint URL is awseb-AWSEB-xxxxxxY1BQF02-xxxx6689.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
- The status is Ready

I will show you the code in Java SDK v2.

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.elasticbeanstalk.ElasticBeanstalkClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.elasticbeanstalk.model.DescribeApplicationsResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.elasticbeanstalk.model.ApplicationDescription;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.elasticbeanstalk.model.DescribeEnvironmentsRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.elasticbeanstalk.model.DescribeEnvironmentsResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.elasticbeanstalk.model.EnvironmentDescription;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.elasticbeanstalk.model.ElasticBeanstalkException;
import java.util.List;
//snippet-end:[eb.java2.describe_app.import]


/**
 * Before running this Java V2 code example, set up your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For more information, see the following documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */

public class DescribeApplications {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        ElasticBeanstalkClient beanstalkClient = ElasticBeanstalkClient.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        describeApps(beanstalkClient);
    }

    //snippet-start:[eb.java2.describe_app.main]
    public static void describeApps(ElasticBeanstalkClient beanstalkClient) {

        try {
            DescribeApplicationsResponse applicationsResponse = beanstalkClient.describeApplications();
            List<ApplicationDescription> apps = applicationsResponse.applications();
            for (ApplicationDescription app: apps) {
                System.out.println("The application name is "+app.applicationName());
                DescribeEnvironmentsRequest desRequest =  DescribeEnvironmentsRequest.builder()
                            .applicationName(app.applicationName())
                            .build();

                DescribeEnvironmentsResponse res = beanstalkClient.describeEnvironments(desRequest) ;
                List<EnvironmentDescription> envDesc = res.environments();
                for (EnvironmentDescription desc: envDesc) {
                    System.out.println("The Environment ARN is "+desc.environmentArn());
                    System.out.println("The Endpoint URL is "+ desc.endpointURL());
                    System.out.println("The status is "+ desc.status());
                }
            }
        } catch (ElasticBeanstalkException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    //snippet-end:[eb.java2.describe_app.main]
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. So, say that I have one EB application which has at some point 5 ECs running (as the app hasn't needed to scale up and 5 is the minimum). Can one running instance get the direct endpoint of the other 4?

Comment: OK - i see what you mean. This is related to the Auto Scaling API as opposed to the EB API. Look at  https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/autoscaling/AutoScalingClient.html.

Comment: My bad, I didn't have the nodejs tag. Anyhow, this is the Javascript equivalent: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-application-auto-scaling/index.html But... I can't see any way to LIST the current instances! Am I blind?